# Counting odd and even numbers function issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to provide function  which will return object with odd and even numbers. Example: parseNum(12345) // Object{odd: 3, even:2}. I've got my code, but I don't understand why it's not working. Where is the problem?

```
function parseNum(num) {
  var obj = {
    odd: 0,
    even: 0
  };

  var arr = Array.from(num);
  arr.forEach(function(value) {
    if (value % 2 === 0) {
      obj.odd += 1;
    } else {
      obj.even += 1;
    }
  });

  return obj;
}
```

Comment: I don't think `Array.from(num)` will work. You're looking for something like `Array.from(num.toString(10), Number)`, I suppose?

Comment: I recommend to use `for (const value of arr) {` instead of `.forEach`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is not working because a number is not iterable, you should cast it to string first.

```
function parseNum(num) {
  var obj = {
    odd: 0,
    even: 0
  };
  if (typeof num === 'number') {
     num = num.toString();
  }
  var arr = Array.from(num);
  arr.forEach(function(value) {
    if (value % 2 === 0) {
      obj.odd += 1;
    } else {
      obj.even += 1;
    }
  });

  return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier

```
function parseNum(num) {
    const odd = Math.floor(num / 2);
    const even = num - odd;
    return {
        odd,
        even
    }
}
```